# Decrement in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

How can I make something like below using JSTL?

```
if(block > 0)
{
    //doSomething;
}
else   
{
    //idle;
}  
block--;
```

Comment: if you need to ask how to construct an if statement in any language, you have come to the wrong place. Read a basic tutorial...

Comment: @MitchWheat: I mean how to use decrement like block-- using JSTL? if this is the very basic thing, then i would like to learn more.

Comment: @MitchWheat: How can i use it with JSTL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<c:set />`.

```
<c:if test="${empty block}">
   <c:set var="block" value="0" scope="session"/>
</c:if>

<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${block ge 0}">
     ....
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
     .....
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<c:set var="block" scope="session" value="${block-1}"/>
```